# mysqli set time_zone unexpected 'timezone' in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to synchronize the php date and the mysql date.
I have no root privilegies, so I want to do it per connection.

I tried:

```
$mysqli_lk = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd); //ok
$mysqli_lk->set_charset("utf8"); //ok
$mysqli_lk->SET_timezone = ('America/Los_Angeles'); // not working

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //ok
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try that way $mysqli_lk->query("SET timezone = 'GMT'");

Comment: @NimsPatel it does nothing. The time in mysql still the same as I do an insert now().

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best way

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$now = new DateTime();
$mins = $now->getOffset() / 60;
$sgn = ($mins < 0 ? -1 : 1);
$mins = abs($mins);
$hrs = floor($mins / 60);
$mins -= $hrs * 60;
$offset = sprintf('%+d:%02d', $hrs*$sgn, $mins);

$stmt = $mysqli_lk->prepare("SET time_zone='$offset';");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```